# Merge many audio files with specific positions

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have multiple audio files that represent the session. So in one folder I may have:

```
2016-06-22-15-59-59-000.mka
2016-06-22-16-59-59-001.mka
2016-06-22-17-59-59-002.mka
```

Filename is the date and time when this file has been created. For example, first file has been created on June 22, at 15:59. Second one on 16:59.

Audio duration may vary, there is no fixed duration. For example, the user can connect to the session for 5 seconds or for 10 minutes. So the first duration will be 00:05, and the second 10:00.

These files together represent the session - that's why they should be merged. You can think about it as multiple people are calling on the same phone number which is used for audio conference.

For example, Alice, Bob, and John want to discuss something. Alice is calling to the number 555-111-22-33, and the Bob is calling the same number 1 minute later. They talk together for 5 minutes. And 30 minutes later Bob and John call the same number at the same time. And then Alice is joining 1 minute later.

So in this case we have multiple audio streams. These streams will usually overlap, but not always. For example, when Alice is waiting for the Bob at the very beginning, we are already recording her, and there is nobody else in this session, so this audio stream is not overlapping with others.

I'm looking for the best way to merge audio recordings of each person into one single file. So in this file we must hear everyone. And between calls, when Alice, Bob and John are not in the session, there should be just silence.

I'm looking at ffmpeg doc, and can't find options that I can use to create overlapping streams, and specify exact time when the stream should start.

Do you guys know what would be the best way to do it? Maybe I need better tools than just ffmpeg, maybe I just need to use libraries and programming language to create my own program to do that? Thanks

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding the third and fourth paragraphs of your question. Can you please edit them for clarity? Maybe provide some background information?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. Please look again if it makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assign the relative time of the start of the first audio as `t=0`. So, if the first audio recording started at `16:59:23` and the third recording started at `17:14:13`, then the third's relative start time is `14:50`.

With that in mind, the basic command structure is

```
ffmpeg -i first.mka -i second.mka -i third.mka -i fourth.mka
       -filter_complex
         "[1]adelay=184000|184000[b];
          [2]adelay=360000|360000[c];
          [3]adelay=962000|962000[d];
          [0][b][c][d]amix=4"
merged.mka
```

What the command does is delay the relative start of each audio file except the first one to match their real-life relative start times. Then all the delayed audio streams are mixed together. The `amix` filter inserts silence where needed.

`adelay` requires value in milliseconds, so 3 minutes, 4 seconds is 184 seconds is `184000` ms. A value has to be supplied for each channel of an audio stream, so if you're dealing with mono streams, then `[1]adelay=184000[b]` is the syntax.

Comment: in case someone have silence between two sounds - add "amix=4,volume=4", volume=4 will normalize sound volume (but not so good ^) )

Comment: This works, but the volume of the audio tracks seems to be adjusted. I've tried the upper idea with adding volume=4 but doesn't work well. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I have the same problem, when I add volume=4 or any other number, it is adding and increasing sound. Without 'volume', there is no sound at all. Both are not working correctly.